# Why is this javascript not working on my site?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make cascaded dropdown in which states should be filter according to country, I was trying many code nothing to work with my site, One of the code I used is properly work when I use it as a seperate demo testing code and give result according to my requirement but when I used same code with in my project it doesn't work.

My script code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var country = new Array('United State','Indonesia','Thailand','Australia','Germany','Japan');
    var state = new Array();
    state["United State"] = new Array("qw", "we", "er", "rt");
    state["Indonesia"] = new Array("as", "sd", "df");
    function resetForm(theForm) {
        /* reset country */
        theForm.country.options[0] = new Option("Please select a country", "");
        for (var i=0; i<country.length; i++) {
        theForm.country.options[i+1] = new Option(country[i], country[i]);
        }
        theForm.country.options[0].selected = true;
        /* reset state */
        theForm.state.options[0] = new Option("Please select a state", "");
        theForm.state.options[0].selected = true;
    }
    function updatestate(theForm) {
        var make = theForm.country.options[theForm.country.options.selectedIndex].value;
        var newstate = state[make];
        theForm.state.options.length = 0;
        theForm.state.options[0] = new Option("Please select a state", "");
        for (var i=0; i<newstate.length; i++) {
            theForm.state.options[i+1] = new Option(newstate[i], newstate[i]);
        }
        theForm.state.options[0].selected = true;
    }
</script>
```

And my HTML code is also below :

```
<form method="get" name="autoSelectForm">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label>COUNTRY<span style="font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;display:none;">(Max.2)</span></label>
        <select name="country" size="2" style="width:100%; height:25px;" class="choseninput" id="filCountry" onchange="updatestate(this.form)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label>STATE <span style="font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;display:none;">(Max.2)</span></label>
        <select name="state" style="width:100%; height:25px;" class="choseninput" id="filState"></select>
    </div>
<form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error in the console?

Comment: No, nothing error, counrty list showing in dropdown but  states is not showing in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space for United State in your `Array`. First you need to correct that one

```
//var country = new Array('United      State','Indonesia','Thailand','Australia','Germany','Japan');
var country = new Array('United State','Indonesia','Thailand','Australia','Germany','Japan');
```

And what you need to do is before populating state `options` in code, you need to check if the states are defined in `state` array for the chosen `country`. And since you define them as keys like `state["United State"]` and `state["Indonesia"]` , you can use `.hasOwnProperty()` method to check if the chosen country exist or not in `state` array as a `key`.

```
if (!state.hasOwnProperty(make)) return;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sTyRe/)**

Comment: I tried this but same problem again, no states is showing, I don't understand why this can't work in my particular project and works well in other seprate files.

Comment: I guess your problem is the `js` code location. You need to place your `js` code **after** relevant `html`.

Comment: I have already tried this but no solution, is there any js conflict problem because there are many other scripts used in this project

Comment: Well, `state` is a globally defined var in your code which is a name that could be used in different plugins for different purposes. Try changing that name like `_state`

Comment: I tried this solution but no result found, same problem again